# SQL Server Reporting Services: how to use a report parameter in the data-driven query?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2019

I have a report in Reporting Services which should use a data-driven query to create a dynamic file name.

For that I created a stored procedure that accepts 3 parameters:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GenerateReportFilename]
    @ReportName NVARCHAR(100) = 'Report',
    @ReportExtension NVARCHAR(100) = '.xslx',
    @StartDate DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Year INT, @Month INT,  @Day INT,@ReportDate NVARCHAR(20), @Filename NVARCHAR(100)

    -- Extract year and month from the parameter
    SET @Year = YEAR(@StartDate)
    SET @Month = MONTH(@StartDate)
    SET @Day= DAY(@StartDate)

    -- Format year and month as "####-##"
    SET @ReportDate = FORMAT(@Year, '0000') + '-' + FORMAT(@Month, '00') + '-' + FORMAT(@Day, '00')

    -- Construct the filename
    SET @Filename =@ReportName + ' (' +  @ReportDate  + ')' + @ReportExtension

    -- Return the filename
    SELECT @Filename AS ReportFilename
```

This works fine with the test:

```
EXEC sp_GenerateReportFilename  'MyReport', '.xslx', '2023-12-31';
```

But if I try use the SSRS report also called "ReportDate" in the data-driven query, I got an error.

Query:

```
EXEC sp_GenerateReportFilename  'MyReport', '.xslx', @ReportDate
```

Error:

> An error has occurred.
> The dataset cannot be generated. An error occurred while connecting to a data source, or the query is not valid for the data source.

Any idea to fix this problem?

Thank you in advance
Volkan

I tried google, co-pilot and several workarounds without success

Comment: **Side note**: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Thank you @marc_s  did you have a solution for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your procedure states this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GenerateReportFilename]
    @ReportName NVARCHAR(100) = 'Report',
    @ReportExtension NVARCHAR(100) = '.xslx',
    @StartDate DATETIME
AS
```

You are calling the stored procedure using this:

```
EXEC sp_GenerateReportFilename  'MyReport', '.xslx', @ReportDate
```

Yet, your stored procedure uses @Startdate

So the statement should be

```
EXEC sp_GenerateReportFilename  'MyReport', '.xslx', @StartDate
```